# Coldfusion ApplicationStop Function

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am working on a CF9 application, and we have a process that is sometimes required that calls `applicationStop()`

My understanding of this function is that it shuts down the app, and the app is restarted on next request.

I am using this to reload some application scoped variables and third party stuff, however, it appears as though the `onApplicationStart()` function is being called before the `onApplicationEnd()` function has finished processing.

Can anyone confirm if this is intended functionality of the `applicationStop()` function? The problem it is causing me is that in `onApplicationEnd()` I am reseting some application scoped stuff which i want to be re-initialised in `onApplicationStart()`, but if it does not wait until `onApplicationEnd()` finishes then I get into an inconsistent state.

---

**EDIT**
The question was originally really more about whether or not it was expected behaviour that onApplicationStart() was being called whilst onApplicationEnd() was still executing, and I was going to fix my problem with using a lock in onApplicationEnd() to make sure it finished its reloading.

However, I have added a lock:

```
lock scope="application" type="exlusive" timeout="5" {
```

And it just seems to ignore the whole block - none of the code (logging including) is executed, and no exceptions are thrown (exceptions are thrown if a lock timesout before executing right?).  I assume this is related to the fact that we don't really have the complete application scope in the onApplicationEnd()?

Comment: Have you looked at Ben Nadel's article about it at http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1667-Learning-ColdFusion-9-Resetting-Applications-With-ApplicationStop-.htm

Comment: Yes, that seems to talk more about sessions and doesn't really touch on the onApplicationStop() function

Comment: You could try exclusively locking the Application Scope using a CFLOCK with the code contained in onApplicationEnd().  I thought that onApplicationEnd was single threaded so this was not necessary.

Comment: why not just call onApplicationStart() to re-up the application?

Comment: Yeah, I have added the lock to the onApplicationEnd(), I just wanted to understand whether this was the expected/known behaviour.

Comment: The application scope is probably not the best place for data that changes sometimes.

Comment: @DanBracuk its not really data - its an external library we are using, and we use the applicationStop to hot-swap changes to the classes etc

Comment: @Travis originally used applicationStop() as was under the impression that it waited for queued requests to finish and then essentially locked for future requests before reloading the classes (didn't want to do it whilst there were active requests etc) - I assume onApplicationStart would have the same issues?

Comment: Adam Cameron has blogged about how applicationStop() works if you had any questions. http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.com/2012/07/investigation-into-applicationstop.html

Comment: Did see that as well, unfortunately that didn't make things much clearer.

Comment: :-( I hope the new article (in my answer below) makes more sense.

Comment: @Travis: running onApplicationStart() is not the same as the application starting. It often makes little difference, but they're not the same thing. http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/difference-between-events-and-event.html

Comment: It wasn't that the last post didn't make sense, rather it was addressing a different problem/question :)

Comment: @AdamCameron I wasn't suggesting that it did, but if he's just trying to reset the application scope and he initially set the values in `onApplicationStart()` then calling it directly should reset those values without having to stop and restart the application (that was the impression I got from the question). Alternatively, anything that needs to be reset could be done in another cfc and called by onApplicationStart() as well as manually to avoid messing with the application event handlers. Something like appsettings.cfc. :)

Comment: @Travis. It's a poor approach though, as running the method directly isn't single-threaded, so can cause unexpected behaviour and errors for users. Restarting the app queues waiting requests properly. It's bad advice. There's a tool specifically for the job, so why recommend not using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't know the answer for this, so I [researched it moderately thoroughly and published my findings](http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/onapplicationstart-will-run-whilst.html).

The bottom line is you *should* expect it because it does happen. I don't think this is a bug because the `onApplicationStart()` / `onApplicationEnd()` methods are event handlers, and not the events themselves, so that one takes a while to run and the other might also be called in the interim is completely legit.

However I think in reality they should be synchronised, as it's not going to be desirable for the code from each to be running concurrently.

I didn't check the locking thing, but might have a look after that coffee I mentioned in my blog article.

Comment: Great thanks, good to know it is expected behaviour. Will accept this answer but would still like to hear any thoughts you have on how to synchronize the onApplicationEnd function

Comment: Yup, will do. Will feed back tomorrow (need to get work done @ the moment)

Comment: @rhinds: I've solved that locking issue for you mate: http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/preventing-onapplicationstart-from.html